# Estimating an integral in terms of a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $l \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $|l|$ large enough and define 
$$
\Omega(l) := B_{\frac{|l|}{2}}(l).
$$
I would like to know what can be said about the following integral as a function of $l$:
$$
I(l) := \int_{\Omega(l)}f(x,l)\,dx,
$$ 
where
$$
f(x,l) :=\frac{|x|^2}{1 + |x|^2|x-l|^2}
$$

It is fairly clear that we can split the domain:

$$
\Omega(l) = \Omega_1(l) \cup \Omega_2(l),
$$
where
$$
\Omega_1(l) := B_1(l)\quad\text{ and }\quad \Omega_2(l):= B_{\frac{|l|}{2}}(l) \setminus B_1(l)
$$
and then
$$
\int_{\Omega_2(l)}f(x,l)\,dx \leq \int_{\Omega_2(l)}\frac{1}{|x-l|^2}dx \lesssim \log|l|.
$$
But what about the behaviour in the small ball around $l$? Clearly we have a spike growing with $|l|$, as $f(l,l) = |l|^2$, but it dies out 'uniformly', in the sense that if $x_{\epsilon}$ is such that $|x_{\epsilon}-l| = \epsilon$, then
$$
f(x_{\epsilon},l) = \frac{|x_{\epsilon}|^2}{1+|x_{\epsilon}|^2\epsilon^2} \sim \min\{\epsilon^{-2},|l|^2\},
$$ 
so I suppose we do not have a quadratic scaling with $|l|$, but what sort of behaviour is there?

Ideally I would hope for 
$$
\int_{\Omega_1(l)}f(x,l)\,dx \lesssim \log|l|,
$$
but it seems somewhat unlikely due to the spike? Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make the change of variable $y=x-l$, so that the integral becomes
$$
\int_{|y|\le |l|/2}\frac{|y+l|^2}{1+|y+l|^2\,|y|^2}\,dy.
$$
You have shown that 
$$
\int_{1\le|y|\le |l|/2}\frac{|y+l|^2}{1+|y+l|^2\,|y|^2}\,dy\lesssim\log|l|.
$$
Now, if $|l|>1$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{|y|\le 1}\frac{|y+l|^2}{1+|y+l|^2\,|y|^2}\,dy&\le
\int_{|y|\le 1}\frac{(|l|+1)^2}{1+(|l|-1)^2\,|y|^2}\,dy\\
&=2\,\pi\int_0^1\frac{(|l|+1)^2r\,dr}{1+(|l|-1)^2\,r^2}\\
&=\pi\,\frac{(|l|+1)^2}{(|l|-1)^2}\log\bigl(1+(|l|-1)^2\bigr)\\
&\lesssim\log|l|.
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks, this is perfect. A 'semi-rigorous' way of showing this that I came up with soon after writing this question is that instead of looking at $B_1(l)$, one can look at $B_{\epsilon}(l)$ and then the outer region scales like $\log|l|$ for any $\epsilon >0$, which 'essentially' implies that nothing bad can happen in the inner region.